# About the infomation we can confirm by Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

In my EC site, product data have the information below.

・Brand
　・category
　・Sub-category
　・Division
　・Style
　・Color-way
　・Gender
　・Season

Can we send and confirm the information in Google Analytics?
I searched in help, and think only we can send Brand,Category, Sub-category.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

BestRegards,
Kazuhito

Comment: This question isn't directly about coding and should be moved to the Webmasters forum instead

Answer (score 0):

Check "**Enhanced Ecommerce**" for a few more options: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce

It's important to understand, that there are multiple sections. Dependent of what you want to do, you've got other limits. If you want to send "Product Data", then your limits are: id, name, brand, category, variant, price, quantity, coupon, position

As I was in my past also in your situations and at least in my unlucky situation the reality was, that divisions could change... So I would recommend you to use what you have and ensure that you send the SKU. Then you can export GA data and export the actual data of your e-commerce system and map the two data parts over the unique identifier SKU together (VLOOKUP and so on).

If you want everything in GA you also can extend the available fields with any field you want to have over **custom-dimensions/custom-metrics**: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en

If you're going for custom-dimensions/custom-metrics I really can recommend first building a concept and really think also about the future. Otherwise you will regret it.

I hope this helped :)